# How to get all the first level nested node in xml?

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js

I am using Node.js project.  I am using DOM Parser.

```
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var xmldoc = parser.parseFromString(xml,"text/xml");
```

Here XML is the string.

I want to reading all the first level child nodes(not in sub level node).

```
 Node (1)
    Node (2)
       Node (3)
    Node (4)
```

I am stuck with reading node.  All the node are same name with nested.

I am using querySelectorAll("Node").  It gets all the nested node.

How to read all the first level child example: Node2, Node4?

Any one assist me?

Thanks in advance.

Update:

```
  Node (1)
       other node
       ExampleNode
           ExampleNode
       Node (2)
           Node (3)
       Node (4)
       ExampleNode
```

Comment: `xmldoc.children[0].children`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment.

[DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) can parse XML or HTML source stored in a string into a DOM.

Once we have a DOM then we have all the [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document) methods available to us, including standard DOM tree traversal.

> How to get all the first level nested node in xml?

By DOM traversal

```js
var xmlString = '<node>(1)<node>(2)<node>(3)</node></node><node>(4)</node></node>',
    parser = new DOMParser(),
    xmldoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, 'text/xml'),
    firstLevel = xmldoc.children[0].children,
    pre = document.getElementById('out');

pre.textContent = 'Number of first level nodes: ' + firstLevel.length + '\n';
[].forEach.call(firstLevel, function (node) {
    pre.textContent += 'node text: ' + node.firstChild.textContent + '\n';
});
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

To the best of my knowledge there is no way to do this with the current CSS selector API, well not without additional markup.

If selectors are a must, then you can use a 3rd party library like jQuery that extends the CSS selector API.

```js
var xmlString = '<node>(1)<node>(2)<node>(3)</node></node><node>(4)</node></node>',
    xmldoc = $.parseXML(xmlString),
    $firstLevel = $('node:first > node', xmldoc),
    $pre = $('#out');

$pre.append('Number of first level nodes: ' + $firstLevel.length + '\n');
$.each($firstLevel, function (index, node) {
    $pre.append('node text: ' + $(node).contents().eq(0).text() + '\n');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: Any possible to get specific named children nodes?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by named?

Comment: See update(in my question):  How to get ExampleNode only.  It may be different order.  0 or 1 or 2.

Comment: In you updated example you can get the first level `ExampleNode`s with `querySelectorAll('Node > ExampleNode')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath to get `node` elements that is *direct child* of the root `node` element, for example :

```js
var xmlString = '<node>1<node>2<node>3</node></node><node>4</node></node>';
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xmlString, 'text/xml');
var result = doc.evaluate('/node/node', doc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE , null);
var message = "Direct child nodes in this XML document are: ";//}
for(var node = result.iterateNext(); node; node = result.iterateNext())
{
 message += node.textContent + ", ";
}
$('#output').text(message);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

The first `/node` returned the root `node` element, and the 2nd `/node` return *direct child* of the root.

For reference :

- [`Document.evaluate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate)
- [Introduction to using XPath in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript)